# Validation With Java Script and printing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in HTML and that if the fields are left blank, the Javascript will print inside the fields error. Please can some one give me a piece of code that will validate the form and then will print Error on top of the form if its left blank and not inside the fields of the form?

My Form:

```
<form id="contact" onsubmit="checkContactForm(); return false;" onreset="resetForm();">
<p>Fill in the form below to send me a message!</p>    

<div id="errormessage"></div>

<p>
<label for="">  </label>
<input type="text" name="" id="" onfocus="" />

<p>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" onfocus="resetField(this);" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="email">E-mail address:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" onfocus="resetField(this);" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="25" onfocus="resetField(this);"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
</p>
```

My Javascript:

```
var requiredFields = ["name", "email", "message"];

function checkContactForm() {
    var myForm = document.forms[0];
    for (i in requiredFields) {
        fieldName = requiredFields[i];
        if (!myForm[fieldName].value || myForm[fieldName].value == "Error") {
            myForm[fieldName].style.color = "#f66";
            myForm[fieldName].value = "";
            var emptyFields = true;
        }
    }

    if (!emptyFields) { myForm.submit(); }
}

function resetField(myField) {
    if (myField.value == "Error") {
        myField.style.color = "#000";
        myField.value = "";
    }
}

function resetForm(myForm) {
    var myForm = document.forms[0];
    for (i in requiredFields) {
        fieldName = requiredFields[i];
        myForm[fieldName].style.color = "#000";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `for (var i in requiredFields) {` so that `i` doesn't leak to the global scope

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML5 there is a form-validation API (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)

Here you can find a pretty good "tutorial": http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/07/web-form-validation-best-practices-and-tutorials/

Comment: Do note that HTML5 form validation will not work in older browsers (such as IE7 and 8) that do not recognize HTML5. The Mozilla Developer Network's [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) is also far better than W3Schools.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand you want the error will be printed in the #errormessage div, right?
If so you can simply do something like this:

```
function addError(str){
    document.getElementById("errormessage").innnerHTML = document.getElementById("errormessage").innerHTML + str + "<br>";
}

function checkContactForm() {
    var myForm = document.forms[0];
    for (i in requiredFields) {
        fieldName = requiredFields[i];
        if (!myForm[fieldName].value || myForm[fieldName].value == "Error") {
            myForm[fieldName].style.color = "#f66";
            myForm[fieldName].value = "";
            var emptyFields = true;
            addError(fiedlName+" is empty!");
        }
    }

    if (!emptyFields) { myForm.submit(); }
}
```